# C# Hide title in title bar

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, hide, title, taskbar

Is it possible to hide the title of my application in the title bar, but in a way that it still appears on the taskbar? Just like "ShowIcon" just for the title of application?

I'm currently doing it that way with the DWM: but this only works with Vista or higher. Is there a cleaner solution?

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Build >= 6000)
        {
            if (DWM.DwmIsCompositionEnabled())
            {
                M = new DWM.MARGINS();
                DWM.DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(Handle, ref M);
                DWM.WTA_OPTIONS o = new DWM.WTA_OPTIONS();
                o.F = DWM.WTNCA_NODRAWCAPTION | DWM.WTNCA_NODRAWICON;
                o.M = DWM.WTNCA_NODRAWCAPTION | DWM.WTNCA_NODRAWICON;
                DWM.SetWindowThemeAttribute(Handle,
                DWM.WindowThemeAttributeType.WTA_NONCLIENT,
                ref o,
                (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DWM.WTA_OPTIONS))
                );
            }
        }
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a simple and crazy one.. You 'll laugh at this ;)
BUt you can set your Text as empty string ("") in your Form title. It won't show your title either form or task-bar.